# Intellij Idea: is it possible to store search-replace expressions for future reuse?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace

I often need to do complex regex-based find-replace operations in Intellij and apparently, the automatic search history only stores the latest dozen or so expression pairs.

Is there a way to permanently store the find/replace pairs for future reuse? It is a bit cumbersome to have to copy-paste the expressions elsewhere.

Sometimes I might spend several minutes writing a one-off complex regex thinking I won't need later, but then when it turns out I do need to replay it a couple of days later, and it is not in the history anymore.

Is there a built-in way to have the expressions stored permanently, e.g. mark a specific find/replace expression as permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Edit > Find > Replace Structurally` and save your Search and Replacement expressions as templates.

[image]

More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/structural-search-and-replace-dialogs.html).

Comment: It's a bit counter intuitive to have this as a separate feature from the standard find-replace, but this is definitely the answer. Apparently the UI is created based on the underlying implementation. In an ideal case "Structural replace" would be integrated in the main replace dialog rather than exist as a separate flavor of replace.

Comment: Agreed. I suspect many users would see this as standard 'find and replace' behaviour with the distinction between "standard" and "structural" being moot.

Comment: This does not work for me. For a valid regex that works in the search input, the Status message in the Structural Replace window warns about unsupported replacement pattern for, in my case, ECMAScript6.